# Uncaught runtime errors in localhost:3000

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, localhost, create-react-app

I am using the maps JavaScript API (google API) and running into a uncaught runtime error in my react application. The website seems to run fine, so it is difficult to know where this error is coming from. The answer might just be to have the app ignore this warning but a real fix would be ideal.

I did use create-react-app to build this app. I would like to rebuilt this app with out CRA, so if you could direct me to a easy starting place that would be great.

If I am missing any information, leave a comment and I will respond quickly.
More information on the [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6Ps5.png):

Message:

> ### Uncaught runtime errors:
>
> **ERROR**
>
> Script error.
>     at handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:39164:58)
>     at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:39183:7

Also, I was receiving a "'google' is not defined no-undef" error but it was coming from ESlint and I added a /*global google*/ that got rid of it.

Here is the package.json file:

[image]

Here is the react component that is running in the app.js file.

```
/*global google*/ 
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';


const BUSINESS_LATITUDE = 35.090120;
const BUSINESS_LONGITUDE = -80.684870;

const LawnCareMapComponentTest = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const mapRef = useRef(null);
  const mapInstance = useRef(null);
  const markerInstance = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js
key=WORKINGAPIKEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap`;
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.async = true;
    script.defer = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);

    window.initMap = () => {
      const input = inputRef.current;
      const mapContainer = mapRef.current;
      const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

      
      const defaultCenter = {
        lat: BUSINESS_LATITUDE,
        lng: BUSINESS_LONGITUDE,
      };
      mapInstance.current = new google.maps.Map(mapContainer, {
        center: defaultCenter,
        zoom: 15,
      });

      
      markerInstance.current = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: defaultCenter,
        map: mapInstance.current,
      });

      autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', () => {
        const place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        const destination = {
          lat: place.geometry.location.lat(),
          lng: place.geometry.location.lng(),
        };

        
        mapInstance.current.setCenter(destination);
        markerInstance.current.setPosition(destination);

        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: destination,
            map: mapInstance.current,
          });

        const origin = {
            lat: BUSINESS_LATITUDE,
            lng: BUSINESS_LONGITUDE,
          };
          
          const service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
          service.getDistanceMatrix(
            {
              origins: [origin],
              destinations: [destination],
              travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
            },
            (response, status) => {
              if (status === 'OK') {
                const distanceInMeters =
                  response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value;
                const distanceInMiles = distanceInMeters / 1609.34;
          
                if (distanceInMiles <= 40) {
                  //  within 40 miles of the business
                  alert('Within 40 miles!');
                } else {
                  // not within 40 miles of the business
                  alert('Not within 40 miles!');
                }
              } else {
                console.error('Error:', status);
              }
            }
          );
          
      });
    };

    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>See if you Qualify</h1>
      <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
        <input ref={inputRef} type="text" placeholder="Enter your address" />
        <div
          ref={mapRef}
          style={{ width: '300px', height: '300px', marginLeft: '10px' }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LawnCareMapComponentTest;
```

The website working fine but getting errors.

Comment: I was getting similar error "Uncaught runtime errors" but different description.... but it was because of wrong version of node... were you able to solve your issue?

Comment: Not yet but i have not been able to look at it much. I will try tomorrow to see if node is causing the problem.

Comment: Please do not use images to present text.